# Volume of a compact set, not necessarily convex

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness, volume, lattice-orders

Looking through my lecture notes, I came across the notion that if a set $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and convex and $vol(X)=2^n$, then by choosing an $0<\epsilon <1$, then $X\subsetneq (1+\epsilon)X$, by convexity of $X$ which makes sense to me.

But if instead, we are given $vol(X)=1$, where $X$ is compact(but not necessarily convex), is there still reason to believe that for $0<\epsilon <1$, then $X\subsetneq (1+\epsilon)X$. Or can I choose some $\alpha$ instead where $X\subsetneq (1+\alpha)X$, where $\alpha$ has some specified bound.

EDIT: Would we still have the case that $vol((1+\epsilon)X)>vol(X)=1$, regardless of whether or not $(1+\epsilon)X$ contains $X$

Comment: If not convex, then $X$ could have a (big) hole, so that the expanded hole in $(1+\epsilon)X$ could easily intersect (or contain) $X$, e.g thinking of a (hyper)spherical shell with volume 1.

Comment: Ah I see, the expanded hole in $(1+\epsilon)X$ wouldn't cover a small section around the hole of $X$, hence $X$ isn't contained in the larger set.

Comment: Other than convexity, is there any other assumption I can make on the set $X$ such that it $X\subsetneq (1+\epsilon)X$

Comment: You might find Wikipedia's [Balanced set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_set) article interesting, as the property that $X \subseteq \alpha X$ for $|\alpha| \ge 1$ is connected with the notion of *norm* for topological vector space.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm focusing too much on trying to prove a relation I won't need for my question. What I really want to know is whether $vol((1+\epsilon)X) > vol(X) = 1$, regardless of whether or not $vol(1+\epsilon)X$ contains $X$.

Comment: There is apparently something missing in the original setup, where $X$ is convex.  We cannot in general show $X \subsetneq (1+\epsilon)X$ because $X$ may be bounded away from the origin.  E.g. let $X=[3,5]^n$, a closed, convex region with volume $2^n$ as stipulated.  But $(1+\epsilon)X = [(1+\epsilon)3,(1+\epsilon)5]^n$, and $X$ is not properly contained in that for $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$ since the corner $(3,3,\ldots,3) \in X$ is not in the "larger" set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regards the Edit made to the Question, about the "volume" of $(1+\epsilon)X$ in comparison to that of $X$.

Assume $X$ is Lebesgue measurable with "volume" $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then for any $0 \le \epsilon$, the "dilation" $(1+\epsilon)X$ will be Lebesgue measurable with "volume" $(1+\epsilon)^n$.

This is one of the [properties of Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Properties).  More generally if $T$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (of which the dilation above is a special case), then $T(X)$ will again be measurable and have "volume" $|\det(T)|$.